# why is it giving an error saying " reference to max is ambiguous" in line 12 "if(k>=max)"?

Tags: c++

here is my function,max is global;

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int max = 0;
int q = 0;

int func(int a[], int n)
{  
     int k = 1;
    for(int j = q + 1; j < n; j++)
    {
        if(a[j] <= a[j - 1])
        {
            if(k >= max)
            {
                max = k;
                q = j;
            }
            return 0;
       }
        k++;    
    }

    if(k > max)
    {
        max = k;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Here it gives the error that it's ambiguous to compare k with max.
Is it because of max being global?

Comment: It's because the compiler doesn't know if you're talking about your global variable `max` (aka `::max`) or the one in `std` (`std::max`).

Comment: @zev   Just use the qualified name ::max :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you are using std namespace:

```
using namespace std;
```

And there is already an `std::max` which conflicts with your variable `max`.

Comment: so max here is a keyword and can't be used as a variable name?

Comment: no it is not a keyword in C++ language. It is something defined in standard library. So only when you include `namespace std` along with your local variable `max`, the ambiguity arises.